# Laravel, call Artisan from php differs from command line

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a route which calls the Artisan facade to execute:

```
Artisan::call('queue:work --once');
```

And I get :

[image]

But it's strange because in the command line, if i do:

```
php artisan queue:work --once
```

Works everything ok:

[image]

I can use other routes to call for example:

```
Artisan::call('config:clear');
```

And works ok too. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the options value staring with -- are not passed to the string 
you can try :

```
Artisan::call('queue:work', ['--once' => true]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.8 introduced this new method of calling artisan commands:

```
Artisan::call('queue:work --once');
```

In previous releases use this:

```
Artisan::call('queue:work', ['--once' => true]);
```

Answer (score 0):

to call an artisan command from the code and passing some options you need to use an array as a 2nd argument to Artisan::call()

like so :

```
Artisan::call('queue:work', ['--once' => true]); // or whatever options you need
```